# Redirect from SSL HTTPS to HTTP (NO SSL)

Tags: htaccess, redirects, https, joomla, http

Many of my visitors have bookmarked my site already with `https://mydomain.com`. Under the bad advice of a programmer I have put my whole site (Joomla) using SSL.

I do not sell anything or provide any member services. I asked him many times if it would slow my site down - he said it wouldn't. I knew it did, I've researched on this site and realized it does slow the site down because of no cache of the pages. Understood.

Please can someone tell me how to get away from it now. I'm not sure how to approach this, should I add something to my htaccess or my main index.php file? I've looked all over the net, there is much advice for adding redirectives for going from HTTP to HTTPS, but very few answers regarding the opposite of going from HTTPS to HTTP.

Answer (score 4):

redirecting from ssl to non-ssl will cause a warning to pop up in visitors' browser. but if you are not selling, then that may not bother you or them.

.htaccess file, assuming Apache and AllowOverrides All:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS}       =on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)          http://yoursite.com/$1 [L,R]
</IfModule>
```

a visit to any page over SSL will be redirected to non-ssl

Comment: You'll only get a warning when POSTing to non-SSL.